# Passing in a subset of an array to the mean function in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

I have an array of variables and an array of flags, both of length 77. For every observation, the array of flags is made up of consecutive 0's, followed by consecutive 1's (ie, after a flag is a 1, all flags at a later index is a one). I am trying to calculate the mean/std/min/max of the array of variables where its corresponding flag is a 0. This is my macro:

```
%macro meanof_precancel(input, meanstat);
j = 77;
do i = 1 to 77;
    if cancelled_{i} = 1 then do;
        j = i - 1;
        call symputx('lastactive', j);
        leave;
    end;
end;
if j = 0 then &meanstat = 0;
else &meanstat = mean(of &input.1-&input.&lastactive);
%mend;
```

I am having difficulty finding out how to resolve the line:

```
    else &meanstat = mean(of &input.1-&input.&lastactive);
```

Does anybody have a strategy to resolve it to something like the following, for j = 33:

```
    else mean_stats = mean(of total_1-total_33);
```

Thanks in advance.

---

I used another approach in the end, although it requires a creation of 77 new variables. I created a new array which sets each value to missing whenever its corresponding flag is one, and took the mean of this new array. For those interested :

```
%macro meanof_precancel(input, meanstat);
array &input.temp{77};

do i = 1 to 77;
    if not cancelled_{i} then
        &input.temp{i} = &input{i};
    else &input.temp{i} = .;
end;

&meanstat = mean(of &input.temp{*});
%mend;
```

Comment: [this should help](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi22/CODERS/PAPER77.PDF)

Comment: Why is this in a macro, with macro variables?  Couldn't you just loop within a datstep?

Comment: I have many variables I want to do this with (5+ arrays of 77 dimensions). Was hoping to write a macro to avoid repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you figured out you can only sum the values of the entire array, and the reason you were having issues with:

```
else &meanstat = mean(of &input.1-&input.&lastactive);
```

is because the call symputx earlier in the macro isn't executed until the datastep has finished.

here is the corresponding SAS documentation:

> Problem Trying to Reference a SYMPUT-Assigned Value Before It Is
>   Available
>
> One of the most common problems in using SYMPUT is trying to reference
>   a macro variable value assigned by SYMPUT before that variable is
>   created. The failure generally occurs because the statement
>   referencing the macro variable compiles before execution of the CALL
>   SYMPUT statement that assigns the variable's value. The most important
>   fact to remember in using SYMPUT is that it assigns the value of the
>   macro variable during program execution, but macro variable references
>   resolve during the compilation of a step, a global statement used
>   outside a step, or an SCL program.
>
> As a result: •    You cannot use a
>   macro variable reference to retrieve the value of a macro variable in
>   the same program (or step) in which SYMPUT creates that macro variable
>   and assigns it a value.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000210266.htm

this would be destructive of the original data so i would be careful, but it will allow for calculation of std/mean/min/max etc from the original array.

```
%macro precancel_stat(input, statvar, stat);
j = 77;
do i = 1 to 77;
    if cancelled_{i} = 1 then do;
        j = i - 1;
        do k=i to 77;
           &input.{k}=.; 
        end; 
        i=77;
    end;
end;
if j = 0 then &statvar = 0;
else &statvar = &stat.(of &input.{*});   
%mend; 

/* test datasets*/
data test;    
array sum_me{77} sum1 - sum77; 
array cancelled_{77} cancelled1  - cancelled77; 
do k=1 to 10; 
 do i =1 to 77; 
     sum_me{i}=i; 
    if i lt 33+k then cancelled_{i}=0; else cancelled_{i}=1;  
 end; 
output; 
end; 
run; 

/* test the macro call*/
data testit ; 
set test (drop= i  k ); 
array sum_me{77} sum1 - sum77; 
array cancelled_{77} cancelled1  - cancelled77; 

 %precancel_stat(sum_me,meanstat,mean);
 %precancel_stat(sum_me,StDev,STD); 
 %precancel_stat(sum_me,MinVal,Min); 
 %precancel_stat(sum_me,MarVal,Max); 
 %precancel_stat(sum_me,SumVal,sum); 

run; 
proc print data=testit; 
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `call symput` that way, because the timing is wrong; you need to know the value of `&lastactive.` during compilation, but you don't actually know it until the data has been looked at.

You can certainly do this with a helper array.  I would use a `temporary` array for this purpose, if you're going to do it that way (`array &input.temp[77] _temporary_;`) as it won't be written out uselessly to the final dataset and resides only in memory.

Honestly, you might be best off just having two variables, the mean-variable and a counter (your `j` is that already, basically).  Instead of putting it in the temporary array, just

```
meanvar=meanvar+input[i];
```

And then at the end of the loop

```
meanvar=meanvar/j;
```

That seems more efficient.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I was hesitant to do the second method as I wanted to simply copy the macro and reproduce it with a std, min and max function. Of course, I could always calculate this manually.